# preferredStatusBarHidden in custom cell and object class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistatusbar

Since **setStatusBarHidden** is deprecated, we will be using **preferredStatusBarHidden** in `UIViewControllers`. But, how do I hide and show easily in a object class or custom `UITableviewCell` class. We used to hide show using `UIApplication` like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Now it is deprecated and it can be used only in `UIViewControllers`, is there a way to hide them in custom tableview cells and `NSObject` classes?

Comment: As the status bar display is controlled by the UIViewController what is the scenario where you require to execute the code on anything other than a UIViewController?

Comment: @nOOb_iOS if my answer works for you please mark it as right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`prefersStatusBarHidden` is a method of `UIViewController` objects, not `UIApplication`. So you should set it on `UIViewController`. Like this.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {

   return NO;
}
```

**Note:**

- If you change the return value for this method, call the `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` method.
- For `childViewController`, To specify that a child view controller should control preferred status bar hidden/unhidden state, implement the `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` method.

**if you want to more dynamically hide or show the status bar**

You can apply logic like this,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { shouldHideStatusBar = (shouldHideStatusBar)? NO: YES; [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]; }
```

You can add this code to your button event as well

make sure to add to your info.plist "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES otherwise things just don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need is a Base VC that you will be subclassing in the VC's you want to control the status bar.
In there you will be subscribing for a given Notification, which when sent will control the status bar of the VC.

**Here is the code:**

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static var statusBarShowHide: Notification.Name {
        return .init(rawValue: "StatusBar.showHide")
    }
}

class StatusBarControllableVC : UIViewController {

    private var statusBarHidden = false

    private func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        while topController?.presentedViewController != nil {
            topController = topController?.presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return statusBarHidden
    }

    @objc func statusBarShowHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else {return}
        let topController = topViewController()

        if let hidden = userInfo["hidden"] as? Bool, self == topController {
            statusBarHidden = hidden
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(statusBarShowHide(notification:)), name: .statusBarShowHide, object: nil)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Now whenever you need to show or hide the Status Bar, you will post a Notification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .statusBarShowHide, object: nil, userInfo: ["hidden":true])
```

I believe this is the simplest approach.
In the code above I'm only showing/hiding the Status Bar on the Top Most View Controller, but obviously you can change that